# Change Google KeyBoard theme to default theme programmatically on Android 13

Tags: gboard

The Google Keyboard on Android 13 defaults to the 'Dynamic Color' theme, featuring a colored background on the keyboard. My application has device owner rights.
How can I programmatically change the keyboard theme to the 'Default' theme without requiring device root options?
Are there any Managed Config options available for the Google Keyboard that facilitate this?

I contacted the mobile manufacturer, and they indicated that there should be a solution, pointing out that the SOTI MDM app has already implemented it in their application.